# How to add CRC32 hash to the data returned as ByteRangeStreamContent?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, httpresponse, httpcontent

I receive request to receive file content from WebApi.

The request can also contain `range` header and so for that I use `ByteRangeStreamContent` to generate the content and then finally send this content as `HttpResponse`.

This is the code that I use

```
var contentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
var bytes = fileProvider.GetFile(fileId);
var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);

if (Request.Headers.Range != null)
{
     var content = new ByteRangeStreamContent(stream, Request.Headers.Range, contentType);
     return ByteArrayHttpResponseMessage(content);
}
else
{
     var content = new ByteArrayContent(stream.ToArray());
     return ByteArrayHttpResponseMessage(content);
}
```

I have to add CRC32 check with the data now.

This I can do easily when the range header is not sent, because then I have access the byte array which I can use to calculate and add CRC32.

The problem arises when the range variable is sent, because then I don't have access to the actual data in byte array form that is being sent, I only have `ByteRangeStreamContent` and so I cannot update it with CRC32 before sending.

I checked that it does have the method `ReadAsByteArrayAsync()`, but I don't know if it is the right way to extract array from `ByteRangeStreamContent` then add CRC32 to the array then again try to generate updated `ByteRangeStreamContent` object.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: If you have a stream add the CRC to the end of the stream.  Use a memorystream.  You can fill the stream with bytes and then after the stream is filled move the position to position zero and read stream to calculate the CRC.

Comment: @jdweng - Please read the question, I have explain that I have the byte array but after reading it to `ByteRangeStreamContent` I no more have bytes array of that range where I can add CRC. That is the main problem

Comment: The either resize the array or use a list where you can add the additional CRC bytes.  Or if you have a stream simply write the CRC bytes to end of stream.

Comment: @jdweng - Please read the question

Comment: I've read the question over 10 times.  If you have a memory stream you can move position to zero and then perform CRC over entire stream, and then add 4 more bytes to the stream.

Comment: Got it, but when we have it inside `ByteRangeStreamContent` the stream will not be same as the original stream, right? So for e.g. if I have stream from 1-100 and I have passed range from 10-50, the final data for me would be 10-50, right? So I have to calculate CRC32 of 10-50 and not the entire stream 1-100, so to add CRC32 to 10-50, I must have access to this small stream or bytes but once it is passed to `ByteRangeStreamContent`, I no more have access to this small ranged stream. Is my understanding right or I am understanding it wrongly?

Comment: @jdweng - Added more details of the code

Comment: I do not know the exact requirements of which bytes (or entire bytes) get the CRC and do not really care.  A memorystream you can read any position of the stream to perform the CRC.  You can also add 4 additional bytes (CRC) to end of the stream.  Your request has a Header and a body.  I believe the CRC is usually put on the Body and not the headers.  The content is usually the body (can be on headers).  As I said I do not know the requirements.  Just that a memory stream is bytes and you can read any range of bytes to perform the CRC.